# Microsoft Graph support for creating document sets and managed metadata term columns

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I recently started testing the Microsoft Graph APIs, I've been able to successfully upload and delete documents in SharePoint Online document libraries through it.

I have not seen anything documentation around this and would guess it's not supported but wanted to confirm, in case I missed it - Does the Microsoft Graph API support creating document sets and/or updating managed metadata columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, the managed metadata should **have not** been supported. Although no official docs states this.

If you cannot get the information by the **expand=fields** too, I'd suggest you to submit a feature request first: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/